# Write each date in date range to the db

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, edmx

I'm trying to take a start and end date and create a row in the db for each day from the start to the end date. The rf_date column should be writing the date from the loop to the db. My problem is that the date that gets written to the db is todays date.

```
if (booking.arrival_date != null && booking.departure_date != null)
{
DateTime startDate;
DateTime.TryParse(booking.arrival_date.ToString(), out startDate);

DateTime endDate;
DateTime.TryParse(booking.departure_date.ToString(), out endDate);

for (DateTime date = startDate; date <= endDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
{
    bookingRoomFlow newroomflow = new bookingRoomFlow();
    newroomflow.bookingid = bookingid;
    newroomflow.rf_date = date;

    roomflows.Add(newroomflow);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.bookingroomflows.Add(newroomflow);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
}
```

Are there any obvious issues with my code?

Comment: Have you confirmed, before the date is added to the database - that the value being added is correct?

Comment: well, I'm getting the date from a datetime field in the database and this code is wrapped in a "if date" (I've updatee the code above), so I'm pretty confident...

Comment: Put a breakpoint there and step through it.  You'll know for sure that way.

Comment: Yeah I would just confirm that first. It might be that the date going into the database is incorrect.

Comment: ok - I stepped through and the correct values were in the autos. At, newroomflow.rf_date = date; the correct date was there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's something else, because your loop code looks about right. I tested it with sample start, end dates as follows.

```
namespace DateIncrementTest
{
    using System;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProcessDates();
            Console.WriteLine("Press a key to Exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void ProcessDates()
        {
            DateTime startDate;
            DateTime.TryParse("1/1/2013", out startDate);

            DateTime endDate;
            DateTime.TryParse("1/7/2013", out endDate);

            for (DateTime date = startDate; date <= endDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Current Value for Date = {0}", date.ToShortDateString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Console Output is as follows.**

```
Current Value for Date = 1/1/2013
Current Value for Date = 1/2/2013
Current Value for Date = 1/3/2013
Current Value for Date = 1/4/2013
Current Value for Date = 1/5/2013
Current Value for Date = 1/6/2013
Current Value for Date = 1/7/2013
Press a key to Exit...
```

Did you check to see

1. If there are any triggers on that table that update the value of column to the current date? or
2. If the column has a default value that sets it to current date, and somehow a null value is getting passed in the update that is making the default value kick in?

Comment: @EthanPelton So... what was the problem?

Comment: auto value in the db - getDate() - however, removing that may not have solved the whole issue. Its now not doing anything - no error, no data - but I'm on the way out the door. I'll try to let you know next week.

Comment: The last issue was that I still had .Property(d => d.rf_date).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);

Everything is working now.